# How to save the active workbook in another folder in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automatically save my active workbook into another folder on my computer and if there is already a file with the name of my workbook in that folder, then it should be saved with "_v1"/"_v2" and so on at the end of its name.
I have found this code but it works just for the current folder, where the workbook is saved.

```
Sub SaveNewVersion_Excel()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim SaveExt As String
Dim VersionExt As String
Dim Saved As Boolean
Dim x As Long

TestStr = ""
Saved = False
x = 2

VersionExt = "_v"

On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
    myPath = "O:\Operations\Department\Data Bank Coordinator\_PROJECTS_\QC BeadRegion Check\Multi Ref Archiv"
    myFileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))
  On Error GoTo 0

If InStr(1, myFileName, VersionExt) > 1 Then
    myArray = Split(myFileName, VersionExt)
    SaveName = myArray(0)
  Else
    SaveName = myFileName
  End If

If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt) = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.saveAs FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt
    Exit Sub
  End If

Do While Saved = False
    If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt) = False Then
      ActiveWorkbook.saveAs FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt
      Saved = True
    Else
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Loop
Exit Sub

NotSavedYet:
  MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
    "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"
End Sub


Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean

Dim TestStr As String

  On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If TestStr = "" Then
    FileExist = False
  Else
    FileExist = True
  End If

End Function
```

It works for the current folder but when I change the folder path it doesn't work.
I would very much appreciate it if you could help me.

Thanks!
Sergiu

Comment: What error are you seeing when you try to specify the file path?

Comment: I am not sure that your `myPath` string is correct. It is only a folder and in the next line your code looks for a dot (.)... Anyhow, a simpler way of obtaining the file name would be: `myFileName = Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "\"))`

Comment: `myPath` should be full **file** name, not just folder

Comment: I changed FolderPath to FolderPath = "D:\_PROJECTS_\Multi Ref Archiv" but instead of saving the file there it saves the file in the same folder under the Name "Multi Ref Archiv" and if there is another version with this name then it is writing the name double.

Comment: `I have found this code but it works just for the current folder, where the workbook is saved.` What did you try to make it work? Can you share that part of the code?

Comment: What this part of your  code (`SaveName = myArray(0)`) return ? Does your code reach this part?

Comment: Also I changed myPath to 'myPath=ActiveWorkbook.FullName' and the folderPath to 'FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))' and it works fine in the current folder. It saves the workbook with "v1" at the end but I need to change the Folder where the workbook is beeing saved

Comment: Did you check if your code reach this part `SaveName = myArray(0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assumed the new folder is "D:_PROJECTS_\Multi Ref Archiv" and that if the existing file is zzzz_v07.xlsm then you want this saved as zzzz_v08.xlsm even when there are no previous versions in the folder. I added the leading zero so they sort nicely!

```
Sub SaveNewVersion_Excel2()

    Const FOLDER = "D:\_PROJECTS_\Multi Ref Archiv" ' new location
    Const MAX_FILES = 99

    Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, bOK As Boolean, res As Variant
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim sFilename As String, sFilename_v As String

    ' filename only
    sFilename = ThisWorkbook.Name

    ' check folder exists
    If Not oFSO.folderexists(FOLDER) Then
        bOK = MsgBox(FOLDER & " does not exist. Do you want to create ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm")
        If bOK Then
            oFSO.createFolder FOLDER
            MsgBox "OK created " & FOLDER, vbInformation
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ' get next name
    sFilename_v = Next_v(sFilename)

    ' check if exists
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
    Do While oFSO.fileexists(FOLDER & "\" & sFilename_v) = True And i <= MAX_FILES
        i = i + 1
        sFilename_v = Next_v(sFilename_v)
    Loop

    ' check loop ok
    If i > MAX_FILES Then
        MsgBox "More than " & MAX_FILES & " files already exist", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    sFilename_v = FOLDER & "\" & sFilename_v

    ' confirm save
    res = MsgBox("Do you want to save to " & sFilename_v, vbYesNo, "Confirm")
    If res = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFilename_v
        MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub

Function Next_v(s As String)

    Const ver = "_v"
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, ext As String, rev As Integer

    i = InStrRev(s, ".")
    j = InStrRev(s, ver)
    ext = Mid(s, i)

    ' increment existing _v if exists
    If j > 0 Then
        rev = Mid(s, j + 2, i - j - 2)
        s = Left(s, j - 1)
    Else
        rev = 0
        s = Left(s, i - 1)
    End If
    Next_v = s & ver & Format(rev + 1, "00") & ext

End Function
```

Comment: This is great!!! It worked perfectly! Thank you all for your help! I appreciate it :)
Sergiu

Answer (score 0):

You can move all of the logic out to a separate function, then you only need to call that to get the "correct" name to save as.

```
'Pass in the full path and filename
' Append "_Vx" while the passed filename is found in the folder
' Returns empty string if the path is not valid
Function NextFileName(fPath As String)
    Const V As String = "_V"
    Dim fso, i, p, base, ext

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    'valid parent folder?
    If fso.folderexists(fso.GetParentFolderName(fPath)) Then
        p = fPath
        ext = fso.getextensionname(p)
        base = Left(p, Len(p) - (1 + Len(ext))) 'base name without extension
        i = 1
        Do While fso.fileexists(p)
            i = i + 1
            p = base & (V & i) & "." & ext
        Loop
    End If
    NextFileName = p
End Function
```

Comment: @CDP1802 - of course thanks for the heads-up.  Fixed.